# how to use subquery in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Query

```
 select * from tbl_emp 
    where emp_salary=(
       select  top 1 emp_salary from 
       (
          select  distinct top 3 emp_salary 
          from tbl_emp 
          order by emp_salary desc
        )
    )a
    order by emp_salary 
    or emp_salary=
    (select * from tbl_emp)
```

Error

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

Comment: It would be easier to split up your query rather than use subqueries.

Comment: http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/subqueries.php

Comment: this is a really good example of how you shouldn't ask question on SO.

Answer (score 0):

You have mixed `where` and `order by` here:

```
where .....some conditions....
order by emp_salary or emp_salary=
(select * from tbl_emp)
```

Revise your query and find appropriate place for that `order by`

Answer (score 0):

Laying out the query makes it much more readable (indentation is your friend!)

There were two problems. first you were naming the wrong subquery with `a` due to the `)` bracket being in the wrong place. Secondly I removed the `ORDER BY` as I'm unsure why it's needed and it was causing an error.

```
select *
from tbl_emp 
where emp_salary = (select  top 1 emp_salary 
                    from  (select  distinct top 3 emp_salary
                           from tbl_emp 
                           order by emp_salary desc) a)
--order by emp_salary 
or emp_salary=(select * from tbl_emp)
```

Now refactoring the query. First you can see the the inner subquery isn't needed

```
select *
from tbl_emp 
where emp_salary = (select top 1 emp_salary 
                    from tbl_emp 
                    order by emp_salary desc)
--order by emp_salary 
or emp_salary=(select * from tbl_emp)
```

Finally it's worth pointing out the last part (the `OR` clause) will only work if `tbl_emp` has EXACTLY 1 column and EXACTLY 1 row, in other words, it must return a single value otherwise you will get one of these errors:

---

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

---

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.